# How do I tell in java if I am in the middle of time-period?

Tags: java, datetime

As part of my project, I have to write a utility function which takes up start-time and end-time and I have to tell whether I am in the middle of that duration or not. For e.g.

Input timeframe duration :2 pm - 4 pm
Current time: 3 pm 
Return : true

I can get the current epoch timethrough `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but how do I tell whether I am past 2 o'clock or 3 o'clock of the same date?

Comment: Which API are you using? (java.util.Date (urgh), Joda Time, or java.time?) What time zone are you interested in?

Comment: Give a look at [Java's Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: @JonSkeet time zone of the java program. 2 o'clock to 4 o'clock of the timezone java program is running in

Comment: Reading the doc, the Date class has a getHours() method that could have helped. Unfortunately it's deprecated but the doc says to use Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) instead. That should do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple idiom with `Calendar`:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar before = Calendar.getInstance();
before.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
before.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
Calendar after = Calendar.getInstance();
after.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
after.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
System.out.println(now.before(after) && now.after(before));
```

**Output** (between 14 and 16)

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current hour of day with Calendar - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR);

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar.getInstance() to get the current time

```
// date time now
Calendar from=Calendar.getInstance();
// set to 14:00:00
from.set(Calendar.HOUR,14);
from.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
from.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

// date time now
Calendar to=Calendar.getInstance();
// set to 16:00:00
to.set(Calendar.HOUR,16);
to.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
to.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

// date time now
Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();

boolean value=now.getTimeInMillis()>from.getTimeInMillis()&& now.getTimeInMillis()<to.getTimeInMillis();

System.out.println("now is between provided period? "+value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html):

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(14, 0, 0);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(16, 0, 0);
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();

return now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(end);
```

Note that on day light saving days this may or may not work as you expect due to the time change. If you want those cases probably accounted for you can switch to a `ZonedDateTime` for example.